# web scraping to csv file getting only the first row

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to get a bunch of tables from Wikipedia,this is my code

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors:_A%E2%80%93F"
html=urlopen(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
table=soup.find('table',class_='wikitable sortable')
rows=table.findAll('tr')
csvFile=open("colors.csv",'w+')
writer=csv.writer(csvFile)
try:
    for row in rows:
        csvRow=[]
        for cell in row.findAll(['td','th']):
            csvRow.append(cell.get_text().decode("utf-8"))
        try:
            writer.writerow(csvRow)
        except AttributeError: 
            print "--"
            continue
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    print "=="
finally:
    csvFile.close()
```

I wanted to write a simple code but i got so many errors so i added some exceptions to fix,but i am still getting only the first row,any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to encode, not decode.

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors:_A%E2%80%93F"
html=urlopen(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
table=soup.find('table',class_='wikitable sortable')
rows=table.findAll('tr')
csvFile=open("colors.csv",'w+')
writer=csv.writer(csvFile)
for row in rows:
    csvRow=[]
    for cell in row.findAll(['td','th']):
        csvRow.append(cell.get_text().encode("utf-8"))
        print(cell.get_text())
    writer.writerow(csvRow)

csvFile.close()
```